# Ubuntu Core 16 on <no ip address> (tty1) after reboot

Tags: ubuntu-core

I'm experimenting this error when Ubuntu Core automatically reboot after a couple of minutes after being activated for the first time, both with DHCP or Static IPv4 configuration DONE:

Ubuntu Core 16 on  (tty1)

You cannot log in until the system has an IP address. 
(Is there supposed to be a DHCP server running on your network?)
Ubuntu Core 18 on  (tty1)

You cannot log in until the system has an IP address. 
(Is there supposed to be a DHCP server running on your network?)

Personalize your account at https://login.ubuntu.com

Comment: Your network is down and Ubuntu Core wants an internet.

Comment: As i've described when i'm setting initial configuration it's works and connect to Ubuntu One account .... then after an automatic reboot that append after a couple of minutes i get this view ... and i'm unable to do anything !!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! Install the right one of these image for Raspberry Pi 4 :

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/18/stable/current/ubuntu-core-18-arm64+raspi.img.xz
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/18/stable/current/ubuntu-core-18-armhf+raspi.img.xz